# How to make the three dots appear in the Android toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am new in Android applications development, and I am trying to develop an application in UI I added a toolbar but In don't know why the three dots in  the right side of the toolbar, it is necessary for me because I want to add a logout button there.

[image]

here is the toolbar layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And here is where i add the toolbar inside the activity class:

```
 toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_button_background_color_focused));
```

and this is my menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".HomeActivity">


    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"

        android:title="Settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search">
        </item>
</menu>
```

And what is weird is that in the android studio preview the three dots are shown:

[image]

what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to remove your menu file in **onCreateOptionmenu()** method

Comment: @RahulKhurana when i remove the file in onCreateOptionsMenu, the icons disappears and the dots do not appear

Comment: what is your actual probelm ?

Comment: it stills the same, the three dots do not appear

Comment: you have to change in your menu file. 

 **app:showAsAction="never"** on both menu items. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, but even with: **app:showAsAction="never"** the dots did not appear, i edited my question again

Comment: have you inflated your view in onCreateOptionmenu() method? try changing your popup theme

Comment: @RahulKhurana yes i inflate it this way: 
 
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        Log.d(TAG ,"onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) - Ini");

       MenuInflater inflater  =  getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        Log.d(TAG ,"onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) - Fi");
        return  true;
    }

how can i change the popup theme  ?

Comment: @RahulKhurana I think i know what is the problem i think is the color, with:
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(), i could change the Media4You color, but do you know how can i change the other side of the bar' s color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three dots were hidden because they were black, and the toolbar background is black, so I had to add this white theme

```
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
```

to my toolbar layout.

Comment: and you forgot to mention, you also had to change showAsAction="never"

Answer (score 4):

Create `Android Resource Directory` of type `menu` in `res` folder and add `xml` file named: 
**user_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout_menu"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_logout"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

In your Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.user_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.logout_menu:
            // Do whatever you want to do on logout click.
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.Overflow.Icon</item>
 </style>

 <style name="ActionButton.Overflow.Icon" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
     <item name="android:src">@mipmap/yourwanticon</item>
 </style>
Try this to change the icon color using this . You have to include three dots png in your drawable folder and set it like this

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreateOptionmenu()` one file will be inflating automatically. Remove that file and three dots will be removed. 
Or 
If this function is not included in your activity file then remove the file under res\menu folder.

Comment: hey could you please clarify what do you need logout button or search ?

Comment: i want to change the three vertical dots color