# Add three dots in toolbar

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, android-menu

I used [this way](https://gist.github.com/anandbose/7d6efb35c900eaba3b26) to make a navigation drawer and show it in my activities. Then I added a `Toolbar` to my base layout. After these steps I tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39546255/6155559) to show three dots on my activities. (I made all changes in my base layout and its class).

Then I saw no changes in my activities. I think I should use another way to add three dots in base activity. How should I do it?

**app_base_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:openDrawer="right">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_header_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**AppBaseActivity.java** is mostly like [this](https://gist.github.com/anandbose/7d6efb35c900eaba3b26) (With small changes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can download `vertical more` icon from Google material icons, extract and add to your `resource/drawable` folder:
https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=more&icon=more_vert&style=baseline

After that create in `menu` folder your `xml` which you are going to inflate to the `Toolbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/moreVertical"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_vertical_24dp" <!--or whatever you called it -->
    android:title="@string/more"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Override `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside your `Actvity` for example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Connect your `Toolbar` with its `id` and than use:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: All I needed was `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`.

Comment: And how can I change "more options"? (Hint text of three dots menu)

Answer (score -1):

Right-click res folder and create a new Resource Directory of type menu. Right-click the menu directory and create a new resource file. From there you can drag and drop a menu item from the XML design. That should give you the 3 dots.

[image]